# Why isn't my state being updated when using useReducer or useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form that renders a child component when it is submitted. I then want to submit the child form and trigger an action in the parent component. The problem is that the state is not being updated in the parent component when I trigger the action in the child.

I have tried using both `useState` and `useReducer` hooks. I read that React hooks are not always executed synchronously, so I tried making the function async and awaiting the hook calls. Since state updates are queued, I also tried wrapping the parent function in a `setTimeout(0)`. None of this has worked. I have the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` with both rules set, and I am not getting errors/warnings, so I know the hook calls are not incorrect. Here is the current code, with `useReducer` and a `setTimeout`:

Parent

```
const initialState = { termsAccepted: false, showTerms: false };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "toggleShowTerms":
      return { ...state, showTerms: !state.showTerms };
    case "toggleTermsAccepted":
      return { ...state, termsAccepted: !state.termsAccepted };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

...
 const openTerms = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "toggleShowTerms" });
  };

  const exitTerms = accepted => {
    dispatch({ type: "toggleShowTerms" });
    dispatch({ type: "toggleTermsAccepted" });
    setTimeout(() => handleTermsAndSubmit(), 0);
  };

const handleTermsAndSubmit = () => {
// state is currently: {showTerms: true, termsAccepted: false} 
// I want the exact opposite
}

return ( 
...
Form onSubmit={openTerms}>
...
<child show={state.showTerms} exit={exitTerms} /> 
)
```

child

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(props.show);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(props.show);
  }, [props.show]);

  const toggleChecked = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
  }; 

 return ( 
... 
<Button onClick={() => { props.exit(checked);}}>Submit<Button/> 
)
```

Inside `handleTermsAndSubmit`, state is currently: `{showTerms: true, termsAccepted: false}` but I expect it to be:
`{showTerms: false, termsAccepted: true}`.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Make sure `useReducer` is used as the first in the functional component and declare the reducer function outside of functional component.

Comment: simply `console.log(state)` in "render" (body of functional component), before `return`

Comment: Firstly you are actually sending the value to `child` while also maintaining a state in `child` which in turn is used to update the value in parent that's an anti-pattern take a look at [Controlled Inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Also I don't think your use case mandates a `useReducer` it's still achievable using `useState` which would be a much better option with finer control about what changes.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your suggestions, but no luck. The issue must have something to do with how the function is being triggered in the child component, since all the other state changes in the parent component are working properly (including the first call to toggleShowTerms)